# Highlight HTML entities in Web mode

Tags: font-lock, web-mode

I often edit articles in web-mode (using PHP). Is there some way of fontifying HTML entities (like `&#8211;`, `&eacute;`, and so on)? I'd like them to be a lighter color so that they're easier to see.

I've tried changing the font-lock settings, but the font-lock code in `web-mode.el` is confusing to me since it deals with lots of different web-mode flavors. (I only really care about the PHP mode, if that makes things easier.) I've  tried the following, to no avail:

```
(add-to-list 'web-mode-html-font-lock-keywords
             '("\\&#x?[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]*;?" . font-lock-comment-face))

(add-to-list 'web-mode-php-font-lock-keywords
             '("\\&#x?[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]*;?" . font-lock-comment-face))
```

I have a feeling I'm just not fiddling with the right variable, but I'm not sure  how to find out which one *is* right.

**Update:**

Thanks to @fxbois, it's now super easy: in your config, just do

```
(setq web-mode-enable-html-entities-fontification t)
```

and customize the face `web-mode-html-entity-face`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`web-mode` does not currently support this feature.  Could you post a feature request on the git repo, please? I'll have to modify some of `web-mode.el` to handle this.

Comment: Just did, at https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/574. I'll go ahead and accept this answer, but provide an update once a patch lands.

Comment: (Fixed already; full update in the question.)